# Combine All Address Fields into One Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working to make the following query better:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CONSG.custpartno AS Assembly, SOM.sono AS SO, SOD.line_no AS Rel, PLD.shippedqty AS Qty, INV.descript AS Description, " & _
  "SHIPADDR.shipto AS ShipToCompany, SHIPADDR.address1 AS ShipToAddress, SHIPADDR.address2 AS ShipToAddress2, SHIPADDR.city AS ShipToCity, SHIPADDR.state AS ShipToState, SHIPADDR.zip AS ShipToZip,  " & _
  "BILLADDR.shipto AS BillToCompany, BILLADDR.address1 AS BillToAddress, BILLADDR.address2 AS BillToAddress2, BILLADDR.city AS BillToCity, BILLADDR.state AS BillToState, BILLADDR.zip AS BillToZip " & _
  "FROM inventor AS CONSG INNER JOIN ((((((plmain AS PLM INNER JOIN pldetail AS PLD ON PLM.packlistno = PLD.packlistno) INNER JOIN sodetail AS SOD ON PLD.uniqueln = SOD.uniqueln) INNER JOIN inventor AS INV ON SOD.uniq_key = INV.uniq_key) INNER JOIN somain AS SOM ON PLM.sono = SOM.sono) INNER JOIN shipbill AS SHIPADDR ON PLM.linkadd = SHIPADDR.linkadd) INNER JOIN shipbill AS BILLADDR ON PLM.blinkadd = BILLADDR.linkadd) ON CONSG.int_uniq = INV.uniq_key  " & _
  "WHERE Val(PLM.packlistno) = " & cboPL.value, dbOpenDynaset)
```

I would like to have one field for the Bill To address and one field for the Ship To address instead of all of the individual fields that make up an address.  I would like it in the following format:

```
Company Name
110 Company Street Address
Address second line 
City, State Zip
```

For some addresses there isn't a second address line.  So, I would like to entirely skip that line.  Also, for some reason there is extra space after each field that doesn't need to be there.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CONSG.custpartno AS Assembly, SOM.sono AS SO, SOD.line_no AS Rel, PLD.shippedqty AS Qty, INV.descript AS Description, " & _
  "Trim(SHIPADDR.shipto) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Trim(SHIPADDR.address1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & IIf(Len(Trim(SHIPADDR.address2) & '')<>0,Trim(SHIPADDR.address2) & Chr(13) & Chr(10),'') & Trim(SHIPADDR.city) & ', ' & Trim(SHIPADDR.state) & ' ' & Trim(SHIPADDR.zip) AS ShipTo,   " & _
  "Trim(BILLADDR.shipto) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Trim(BILLADDR.address1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & IIf(Len(Trim(BILLADDR.address2) & '')<>0,Trim(BILLADDR.address2) & Chr(13) & Chr(10),'') & Trim(BILLADDR.city) & ', ' & Trim(BILLADDR.state) & ' ' & Trim(BILLADDR.zip) AS BillTo " & _
  "FROM inventor AS CONSG INNER JOIN ((((((plmain AS PLM INNER JOIN pldetail AS PLD ON PLM.packlistno = PLD.packlistno) INNER JOIN sodetail AS SOD ON PLD.uniqueln = SOD.uniqueln) INNER JOIN inventor AS INV ON SOD.uniq_key = INV.uniq_key) INNER JOIN somain AS SOM ON PLM.sono = SOM.sono) INNER JOIN shipbill AS SHIPADDR ON PLM.linkadd = SHIPADDR.linkadd) INNER JOIN shipbill AS BILLADDR ON PLM.blinkadd = BILLADDR.linkadd) ON CONSG.int_uniq = INV.uniq_key  " & _
  "WHERE Val(PLM.packlistno) = " & cboPL.value, dbOpenDynaset)
```

In the above the `Chr(13)` = Carriage Return and `Chr(10)` = New Line.  I use `Trim()` to remove any leading and trailing spaces of the fields.  Then to NOT have an extra line for a blank Address Line 2 you can check the length and only add to the address if it is greater than 0.